# Cannot find Wine (Stable 3.0.3-bionic) even after I installed it

Tags: software-installation, wine

I followed the instructions on the Winehq website and ran the following command

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

And this was the outcome:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-wine libwine libwine:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 wine32:i386 wine64
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  wine-stable wine-stable-amd64 wine-stable-i386:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  wine-stable-amd64 wine-stable-i386:i386 winehq-stable
The following packages will be upgraded:
  wine-stable
1 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 42.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 386 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 wine-stable-amd64 amd64 3.0.3~bionic [20.8 MB]
Get:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic/main i386 wine-stable-i386 i386 3.0.3~bionic [20.3 MB]
Get:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 wine-stable amd64 3.0.3~bionic [1,115 kB]
Get:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 winehq-stable amd64 3.0.3~bionic [3,214 B]
Fetched 42.2 MB in 60s (705 kB/s)                                              
Selecting previously unselected package wine-stable-amd64.
(Reading database ... 211216 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../wine-stable-amd64_3.0.3~bionic_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wine-stable-amd64 (3.0.3~bionic) ...
Selecting previously unselected package wine-stable-i386:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../wine-stable-i386_3.0.3~bionic_i386.deb ...
Unpacking wine-stable-i386:i386 (3.0.3~bionic) ...
Preparing to unpack .../wine-stable_3.0.3~bionic_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wine-stable (3.0.3~bionic) over (3.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package winehq-stable.
Preparing to unpack .../winehq-stable_3.0.3~bionic_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking winehq-stable (3.0.3~bionic) ...
Setting up wine-stable-amd64 (3.0.3~bionic) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Setting up wine-stable-i386:i386 (3.0.3~bionic) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Setting up wine-stable (3.0.3~bionic) ...
Setting up winehq-stable (3.0.3~bionic) ...
```

Now after this I simply searched for Wine on my computer and it doesn't show up. What do I do now?

Comment: Playonlinux hs the same functions as wine?

Comment: PlayOnLinux works as a front end and will still use wine as back end

Answer (score 2):

Wine doesn't have any kind of front-end. It's just a background kinda app. Thus, it isn't listed in applications. But it is still there. You can check it by running any `.exe` Windows compatible program.

There are some front-end available in Software center of which I use PlayOnLinux. To install PlayOnLinux, run

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```